# Dart: Check Type T of generic function

Tags: dart

I have a generic function. I'm trying to return a value based on the type `T`,
however, my function never seems to match any types (see code below):

```
int _getCollection<T>() {
    print(T); // the actual type
    print(T is ClockData); // ClockData is a class I created

    // always returns false when passing _getCollection<ClockData>()
    if (T is ClockData) { 
      return 1;
    } else if (T is UserData) {
      return 2;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is` operator will check if left operand is an instance of right operand. T is a type parameter and not an instance of `ClockData`. You can use `==` operator to compare those:

```
int _getCollection<T>() {
  if (T == ClockData) { 
    return 1;
  } else if (T == UserData) {
    return 2;
  } else {
    throw Exception();
  }
}
```

Please note this checks for identity and will not support subtypes. If you need to support type inheritance (passing subclasses of `ClockData` as `T`) you can use a trick like this:

```
int _getCollection<T>() {
  if (<T>[] is List<ClockData>) {
    return 1;
  } else if (<T>[] is List<UserData>) {
    return 2;
  } else {
    throw Exception();
  }
}
```

Comment: So 'is' is an instance comparisong and '==' can be used to compare types? And if that's true, then why are you using 'is' in the second example?

Comment: 'is' compares instance to type. == compsers two instances or two types (which are also instances of Type). In second example I am creating an instance of a list as a left operand and checking if this instance is of type on the right. this is a known trick in dart to compare types with support for inheritance. but if you dont need to support inheritance use the first example as it will be faster.

Comment: That makes much more sense now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The class type of `T` is actually `Type`. It's value is ClockData.

`is` checks for Runtimetype and T has runtime type of `Type`. So T is not ClockData.

as @fsw mentioned, == is much better approach.